Can someone explain to me what "data = validated_data.copy()" means?
I wonder why the create method does not process the data directly but has to copy it into data and then process it indirectly, while the returned result is also the processed user.
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    alumni = AlumniSerializer()
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        req = super().to_representation(instance)
        if instance.avatar:
            req['avatar'] = instance.avatar.url
            
        if instance.cover:
            req['cover'] = instance.cover.url
        
        return req
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        data = validated_data.copy()
        user = User(**data)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        
        return user
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'avatar', 'cover', 'alumni']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True
            }
        }


It is not necessary.

You should be safe to remove it. It serves no purpose other than wasting time and memory.

I started to say it is because of future-proofing, to protect data against potential modification (e.g. inside User constructor). But that makes no sense - because **data is used, it is data elements being passed in, not data itself; and since copy was used, not deepcopy, the elements themselves can be changed and influence the contents of the original array. So - yes, completely useless.

The reason of copying the validated_data into a new variable is to ensure that the original validated_data remains unmodified to maintain data integrity and prevent unintended side effects.
So if you change the data while creating a user it wont effect the validated data of the serializer

The .copy() here is non-sensical. Indeed, it makes a copy of the dictionary, but a shallow copy, so if one of the values is a list, it will not copy that list as well, but still refer to the old list.
Now since you perform dictionary unpacking, it will thus read the parameters, and use the key and values to create a User object. One thus could use:
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    alumni = AlumniSerializer()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        req = super().to_representation(instance)
        if instance.avatar:
            req['avatar'] = instance.avatar.url

        if instance.cover:
            req['cover'] = instance.cover.url

        return req

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'username',
            'password',
            'email',
            'avatar',
            'cover',
            'alumni',
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
